# android webview java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.webkit.WebSettings on a null object reference

Tags: nullpointerexception, android-webview, swipe-gesture

I'm trying to implement swipe in a customized WebView, but when the app tries to call getSettings(), a null pointer exception is thrown. Here are the particulars:

First, the extended WebView class:

```
package com.chiaramail.opencomments;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class OpenCommentsWebView extends WebView {
Context context;
GestureDetector gd;

public OpenCommentsWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context);

    this.context = context;
    gd = new GestureDetector(context, sogl);
}

GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener sogl = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        if (e1 == null || e2 == null) return false;
        if (e1.getPointerCount() > 1 || e2.getPointerCount() > 1) return false;
        else {
            try { // Swipe down, so set
                if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > 100 && Math.abs(velocityY) > 800) {
                    MainActivity.recentCommentsShown = false;
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) { // nothing
                Log.e("OpenCommentsWebView", "Swipe error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                //                   Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.update_flow_failed) + BLANK + e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
};

void show_toast(final String text) {
    Toast t = Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    t.show();
}
```

}

The relevant part of the main layout file:

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.chiaramail.opencomments.OpenCommentsWebView
        android:id="@+id/browser_page"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Instantiating the extended WebView object:

```
    private OpenCommentsWebView browser_page;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    activity = this;
    try {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(activity, getString(R.string.install_from_google_play), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
        return;
    }

    current_page = "https://www.google.com/";

    browser_page = findViewById(R.id.browser_page);

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
      super.onStart();

      WebAction();
    }

    .
    .
    .
    public void WebAction() {
    // Fails here.
        browser_page.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }
```